# size of pointer is always equal to size of int in C compiler . Is it correct?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, operating-system

I am using 64bit ubuntu machine (x86_64).
My senior has told that in C program size of any pointer is always equal to size of int . Is it correct ?
But when i execute `sizeof(int)` I am getting 4 bytes and for `sizeof(int*)` I am getting 8 .
1. Why am I getting 4 bytes for `sizeof(int)` in my x86_64?

Comment: Your senior was wrong.

Comment: google gives better answers then your senior ;)

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is dependent on your compiler

Comment: What does "senior" mean in this context? Is it a teacher or a peer? If it's a teacher, we need to ensure somehow that this dangerous misinformation stops.

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted. OP is an excellent person for questioning what he's been taught by an incompetent person.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit...he is from india...senior means a senior colleague or a senior peer either in college or in work place :)

Comment: Well, if by "senior" you mean someone you work for or with, you're pretty much ensured job security because you're going to have a lot of really, really bad code to fix....

Comment: @Tejendra: So what's that, a fellow student in a year above?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit..yupp...you got it right..and a senior might be wrong as in this case

Comment: Okay well hopefully at least the OP will now go to that senior and set them straight, and then the senior can stick it to whatever nincompoop taught them this rubbish in the first place.

Comment: On a typical 32 bit system `sizeof(int)` is _usually_ the same as `sizeof(int*)`. That's probably what your senior had in mind.

Comment: Hey guys why do you down vote . It may be silly for you guys but big thing for me . I thought if it is 32 bit system `sizeof(int)` is always 4 bytes and if it is 64 bit `sizeof(int)` is always 8. Am I wrong. @Light what is that OP means

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya *I thought if it is 32 bit system `sizeof(int)` is always 4 bytes and if it is 64 bit `sizeof(int)` is always 8*  No, `sizeof(int)` actually remains at 4 in the most common memory models you'll see - ILP32 and LP64.  But there are other memory models that exist.  `sizeof(int)` often is 2 or even 8. (Assuming 8-bit bytes)

Comment: I answered this fifteen minutes ago...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what is OP ?

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya: You. It stands for "original poster".

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya Good thing you came here to get some accurate information, rather than believing your misinformed senior.  Sorry about the downvoting -- people here get so angry about seeing wrong information that they sometimes lash out by clicking on the nearest downvote button (thus blaming the messenger in this case).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My senior has told that in C program size of any pointer is always equal to size of int . Is it correct?

**NO, that is not correct**.

There are [multiple different memory models possible](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html), often on the same system at the same time.  Often systems support running ILP32 and LP64 processes at the same time.  While an `int` is 4 bytes (32 bits) in both ILP32 and LP64, pointers are 8 bytes (64 bits) in LP64.

Answer (score 9):

**No, it is not correct.**

Your "senior" is wrong. Your compiler is right (obviously).

The size of an `int` and the size of a pointer vary across platforms, and they are not necessarily the same. Indeed, on modern 64-bit consumer hardware, you're likely to find 32-bit `int`s and 64-bit pointers.

Answer (score 7):

The integer type that may hold a pointer is `intptr_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: That's not an answer but a comment.

Comment: It's a good piece of information, all the same.

Comment: It's a useful enough comment that deserves to be in an answer for more visibility

Answer (score 5):

There is no requirement that pointers always be the same size as an `int`.  In fact, pointers to different types don't have to be the same size as each other:

[Online C 2011 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.2.5 Types**
> ...
> 28 A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.<sup>48)</sup> Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>48) The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.</sup>

For C++, see the [online C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf#page87), section 3.9.2, para 3.

On 32-bit machines it's common for pointer types and `int` to be the same size, but it's not universally true (especially as we move to 64-bit architectures).